# pass form errors in TemplateView in Django?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-users, django-generic-views

This is how my `views.py` looks:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):

    template_name="home.html"

    def dispatch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            raise http.Http404
        return super(HomePageView,self).dispatch(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

my `home.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if  user.is_authenticated %}

 ### display some user specic data
 {% else %}
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
           {% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.ohh!</p>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="form-group">

            {{ form.username.label_tag }}
              <input type="text" placeholder="Uname or Email" class="form-control" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
          </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),)
```

There are two issues I am facing:
when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` (as a GET request), I get 404 error.
In the event of GET request, I still want to redirect to `home.html`, because that will show log in form

In the event of POST request, I want to redirect to 'home.html` that will handle when user logged in.

If there is logging error, I want to pass that information as form.errors to rendered in template.

I am having difficulty implementing these. Any pointers here?

Comment: Should you be using a `FormView` instead of `TemplateView` here? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView

Answer (score 0):

A `FormView` will definitely help you out with dealing with login form validation and error handling:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class LoginView(FormView):
    template_name="login_form.html"
    form_class = LoginForm
    success_url = reverse('home')
```

I wouldn't try to pack to much else into that view though, so I suggest that you split out your `HomePageView` to be a separate view.

`FormView` will give you back the form object populated with field errors and non-field errors that you can then display in your template. Like so:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Uname or Email" class="form-control" name="username">
    {{ form.username.errors }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password">
    {{ form.password.errors }}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

This is explained well in the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template

Answer (score 0):

view code

```
    return render(request, 'my_template.html',
                  context={'form_errors': form.errors})
```

html template code

```
 <span class="error">{{ form_errors.my_form_field_name }}</span>
```